# ¿Cómo poner cada botón de un color con multiplechoice?

Tags: css, html5, botón, twig, background

He creado una pregunta de multiple choice, la selección se realiza en botones, necesitaría que cada botón se mostrara de un color diferente, se muestran todos lo botones iguales. He pensado en crear una clase con *CSS* para cada botón que indique el color, pero no se como aplicar esta clase a cada botón porque el código los mete todos juntos.

Código *CSS*:

```
.btn-sq .btn-group-sq .btn .btn-personal {
    width: 223px;
    height: 226px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 5.5;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #f0005e !important;
}

.btn-sq .btn-group-sq .btn .btn-personal2 {
    width: 223px;
    height: 226px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 5.5;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #f0045e !important;
}

.btn-sq .btn-group-sq .btn .btn-personal3 {
    width: 223px;
    height: 226px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 5.5;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #f0075e !important;
}
```

twig que pone el input del botón:

```
<!-- answer_row -->
<div class="bootstrap-buttons-div col-xs-12 {{ max_buttons_row }} giss">
    <div id='javatbd{{ myfname }}' class="button-item btn btn-primary {{ button_size_class }} {% if checkedState!='' %} active {% endif %} col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="{{ myfname }}"
            data-name="{{myfname}}"
            class="bootstrap-checkbox sr-only"
            id="answer{{ myfname }}"
            {{ checkedState }}
            value="Y"
        />
        {{ dump (myfname)}}

        <label for="answer{{ myfname }}" class="checkbox-label control-label">{{ question }}</label>
        <input
            type="hidden"
            name="java{{ myfname }}"
            id="java{{ myfname }}"
            value="{{ C.Html.encode( sValue ) }}"
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

```
<div class="bootstrap-buttons-div col-xs-12 col-sm-6 giss">
  <div id="javatbd231926X43X171SQ001" class="button-item btn btn-primary btn-sq  col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <input type="checkbox" name="231926X43X171SQ001" data-name="231926X43X171SQ001" class="bootstrap-checkbox sr-only" id="answer231926X43X171SQ001" value="Y">
    <label for="answer231926X43X171SQ001" class="checkbox-label control-label">Opción 1</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="java231926X43X171SQ001" id="java231926X43X171SQ001" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un fragmento de **HTML** donde se vean los diferentes botones a los que quieres afectar?

Comment: se supone que los pinta con el fragmento de arriba que tiene el input, ¿no ?

Comment: Si, pero me gustaría ver el **HTML** que genera el fragmento que nos pones, para así poder ver como los botones a los que quieres afectar están posicionados en el **DOM**.

Comment: ```<div class="bootstrap-buttons-div col-xs-12 col-sm-6 giss">
    <div id="javatbd231926X43X171SQ001" class="button-item btn btn-primary btn-sq  col-xs-12 col-sm-12">

        <input type="checkbox" name="231926X43X171SQ001" data-name="231926X43X171SQ001" class="bootstrap-checkbox sr-only" id="answer231926X43X171SQ001" value="Y">

        <label for="answer231926X43X171SQ001" class="checkbox-label control-label">Opción 1</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="java231926X43X171SQ001" id="java231926X43X171SQ001" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```